# Understanding collections concurrency and Collections.synchronized*

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I learned yesterday that I've been incorrectly using collections with concurrency for many, many years.

Whenever I create a collection that needs to be accessed by more than one thread I wrap it in one of the Collections.synchronized* methods. Then, whenever *mutating* the collection I also wrap it in a synchronized block (I don't know why I was doing this, I must have thought I read it somewhere).

However, after reading the API more closely, it seems you need the synchronized block when *iterating* the collection.  From the API docs (for Map):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views:

And here's a small example:

```
List<O> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<O>());
...
synchronized(list) {
   for(O o: list) { ... }
}
```

So, given this, I have two questions:

- Why is this even necessary?  The only explanation I can think of is they're using a default iterator instead of a managed thread-safe iterator, but they could have created a thread-safe iterator and fixed this mess, right?
- More importantly, what is this accomplishing?  By putting the iteration in a synchronized block you are preventing multiple threads from iterating at the same time.  But another thread could mutate the list while iterating so how does the synchronized block help there?  Wouldn't mutating the list somewhere else screw with the iteration whether it's synchronized or not? What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've rolled back your most recent edit. Please don't edit questions to incorporate the answers in them. Let the question be the question, and the answer be the answer.

Comment: @chris-hayes: Roger that!

Answer (score 7):

> Why is this even necessary? The only explanation I can think of is
>   they're using a default iterator instead of a managed thread-safe
>   iterator, but they could have created a thread-safe iterator and fixed
>   this mess, right?

Iterating works with one element at a time. For the `Iterator` to be thread-safe, they'd need to make a copy of the collection. Failing that, any changes to the underlying `Collection` would affect how you iterate with unpredictable or undefined results.

> More importantly, what is this accomplishing? By putting the iteration
>   in a synchronized block you are preventing multiple threads from
>   iterating at the same time. But another thread could mutate the list
>   while iterating so how does the synchronized block help there?
>   Wouldn't mutating the list somewhere else screw with the iteration
>   whether it's synchronized or not? What am I missing?

The methods of the object returned by `synchronizedList(List)` work by synchronizing on the instance. So no other thread could be adding/removing from the same `List` while you are inside a `synchronized` block on the `List`.

Comment: Everything you said made sense, especially the "synchronizing on the instance", which seems obvious but I didn't realize. And I suppose you need to synchronize on the iteration rather than the mutation because an iteration could be in progress when you synchronize a mutation whereas the other way around would be much less likely to be true (since mutations are faster than iterations).  Thanks again!

Comment: @rjcarr You're synchronizing on both iteration and mutation. The list itself just does the mutation synchronization out of the box (the entire purpose of the `synchronizedList` method). It really boils down to this: it's not safe to mutate the list while something is iterating over it, but the list can't lock itself after it returns the iterator. So you either have to lock the list yourself or use a copy instead. (For a small list, I'd prefer a copy, actually. Much less hassle.)

Answer (score 5):

#### The basic case

All of the methods of the object returned by `Collections.synchronizedList()` are synchronized to the list object itself. Whenever a method is called from one thread, every other thread calling any method of it is blocked until the first call finishes.

So far so good.

#### Iterare necesse est

But that doesn't stop another thread from modifying the collection when you're **between calls** to `next()` on its `Iterator`. And if that happens, your code will fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException`. But if you do the iteration in a `synchronized` block too, and you synchronize on the same object (i.e. the list), this will stop other threads from calling any mutator methods on the list, they have to wait until your iterating thread releases the monitor for the list object. **The key is that the mutator methods are `synchronized` to the same object as your iterator block, this is what's stopping them.**

#### We're not out of the woods yet...

Note though that while the above guarantees basic integrity, it doesn't guarantee correct behaviour at all times. You might have other parts of your code that make assumptions which don't hold up in a multi-threaded environment:

```
List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList( ... );
...
if (!list.contains( "foo" )) {
   // there's nothing stopping another thread from adding "foo" here itself, resulting in two copies existing in the list
   list.add( "foo" );
}
...
synchronized( list ) { //this block guarantees that "foo" will only be added once
  if (!list.contains( "foo" )) {
     list.add( "foo" );
  }
}
```

#### Thread-safe Iterator?

As for the question about a thread-safe iterator, there is indeed a list implementation with it, it's called [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). It is incredibly useful but as indicated in the API doc, it is limited to a handful of use cases only, specifically when your list is only modified very rarely but iterated over so frequently (and by so many threads) that synchronizing iterations would cause a serious bottle-neck. If you use it inappropriately, it can vastly degrade the performance of your application, as each and every modification of the list creates an entire new copy.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronizing on the returned list is necessary, because internal operations synchronize on a `mutex`, and that mutex is `this`, i.e. the synchronized collection itself.

Here's some [relevant code from `Collections`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection), constructors for `SynchronizedCollection`, the root of the synchronized collection hierarchy.

```
    SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {
        if (c==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.c = c;
        mutex = this;
    }
```

(There is another constructor that takes a mutex, used to initialize synchronized "view" collections from methods such as `subList`.)

If you synchronize on the synchronized list itself, then that *does* prevent another thread from mutating the list while you're iterating over it.

The imperative that you synchronize of the synchronized collection itself exists because if you synchronize on anything else, then what you have imagined could happen - another thread mutating the collection while you're iterating over it, because the objects locked are different.

Answer (score 1):

Sotirios Delimanolis [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941150/1441122) your second question "What is this accomplishing?" effectively. I wanted to amplify his answer to your first question:

> Why is this even necessary? The only explanation I can think of is they're using a default iterator instead of a managed thread-safe iterator, but they could have created a thread-safe iterator and fixed this mess, right?

There are several ways to approach making a "thread-safe" iterator. As is typical with software systems, there are multiple possibilities, and they offer different tradeoffs in terms of performance (liveness) and consistency. Off the top of my head I see three possibilities.

**1. Lockout + Fail-fast**

This is what's suggested by the API docs. If you lock the synchronized wrapper object while iterating it (and the rest of the code in the system written correctly, so that mutation method calls also all go through the synchronized wrapper object), the iteration is guaranteed to see a consistent view of the contents of the collection. Each element will be traversed exactly once. The downside, of course, is that other threads are prevented from modifying or even reading the collection while it's being iterated.

A variation of this would use a reader-writer lock to allow reads but not writes during iteration. However, the iteration itself can mutate the collection, so this would spoil consistency for readers. You'd have to write your own wrapper to do this.

The fail-fast comes into play if the lock isn't taken around the iteration and somebody else modifies the collection, or if the lock is taken and somebody violates the locking policy. In this case if the iteration detects that the collection has been mutated out from under it, it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

**2. Copy-on-write**

This is the strategy employed by `CopyOnWriteArrayList` among others. An iterator on such a collection does not require locking, it will always show consistent results during iterator, and it will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, writes will always copy the entire array, which can be expensive. Perhaps more importantly, the notion of *consistency* is altered. The contents of the collection might have changed while you were iterating it -- more precisely, while you were iterating a snapshot of its state some time in the **past** -- so any decisions you might make **now** are potentially out of date.

**3. Weakly Consistent**

This strategy is employed by `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` and similar collections. The specification contains the definition of [weakly consistent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly). This approach also doesn't require any locking, and iteration will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. But the consistency properties are extremely weak. For example, you might attempt to copy the contents of a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` by iterating over it and adding each element encountered to a newly created `List`. But other threads might be modifying the deque while you're iterating it. In particular, if a thread removes an element "behind" where you've already iterated, and then adds an element "ahead" of where you're iterating, the iteration will probably observe both the removed element and the added element. The copy will thus have a "snapshot" that never actually existed at any point in time. Ya gotta admit that's a pretty weak notion of consistency.

The bottom line is that there's no simple notion of making an iterator thread safe that would "fix this mess". There are several different ways -- possibly more than I've explained here -- and they all involve differing tradeoffs. It's unlikely that any one policy will "do the right thing" in all circumstances for all programs.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  I now see I was naive in my expectations and, if nothing else, I understand the problem much better now.